# MYSQL UPDATE Query using expression

Tags: mysql

I have a table say **table1** with columns **id(INT), tag(VARCHAR),tag2(VARCHAR),var1(VARCHAR),var2(VARCHAR) and external_tags(TINY INT)**. There are data only in id, tag and external_tags fields only. I have to update each rows in this table so that value in tag field should be split to tag2 and var1 fields. For example, there are many rows like

| id | tag                              | tag2 | var1 | external_tags |var2

| 1 | school_signup_xxx                                  | NULL | NULL |    0 |NULL

|  2 | course_enroll_213                                  | NULL | NULL |    0 |NULL

|  3 | course_enroll_556                                  | NULL | NULL |    0 |NULL

|  4 | automation_notify_bounced_111_222                  | NULL | NULL |    0 |NULL

|  5 | automation_notify_bounced_666_223                  | NULL | NULL |    0 |NULL

|  6 | automation_notify_bounced_426_253                  | NULL | NULL |    0 |NULL

|  7 | registered_livestream_co_host_111_schedule_444     | NULL | NULL |    0 |NULL

|  8 | registered_livestream_co_host_632_schedule_234     | NULL | NULL |    0 |NULL

|  9 | attended_recurring_live_class_868_rec_schedule_151 | NULL | NULL |    0 |NULL

| 10 | attended_recurring_live_class_545_rec_schedule_747 | NULL | NULL |    0 |NULL

| 11 | manual_in                                          | NULL | NULL |    1 |NULL

| 12 | test tag                                           | NULL | NULL |    1 |NULL

| 13 | test tag abc                                       | NULL | NULL |    1 |NULL

I want to update the above rows in the table table1 as below

| id | tag               | tag2                          | var1 | external_tags |var2

|  1 | school_signup_xxx      | school_signup                 | xxx |             0 |NULL

|  2 | course_enroll_213      | course_enroll                 | 213 |             0 |NULL

|  3 | course_enroll_556      | course_enroll                 | 556 |             0 |NULL

|  4 | automation_notify_bounced_111_222| automation_notify_bounced     | 111 |             0 |222

|  5 | automation_notify_bounced_666_223| automation_notify_bounced     | 666 |             0 |223

|  6 | automation_notify_bounced_426_253| automation_notify_bounced     | 426 |             0 |253

|  7 | registered_livestream_co_host_111_schedule_444     | registered_livestream_co_host | 111 |             0 |444

|  8 | registered_livestream_co_host_632_schedule_234     | registered_livestream_co_host | 632 |             0 |234

|  9 | attended_recurring_live_class_868_rec_schedule_151 | attended_recurring_live_class | 868 |             0 |151

| 10 | attended_recurring_live_class_545_rec_schedule_747 | attended_recurring_live_class | 545 |             0 |747

| 11 | manual_in                                          | manual_in                     | NULL |             1 |NULL

| 12 | test tag                                           | test tag                      | NULL |             1 |NULL
| 13 | test tag abc                                       | test tag abc                  | NULL |             1 |NULL
+----+-------------------+------+------+---------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------

There are 6 cases

1. If external_tags = 0 and tag = school_signup_{var1value} then update tag2 to school_signup and var1 to var1value
2. If external_tags = 0 and tag = course_enrolled_{var1value} then update tag2 to course_enrolled and var1 to var1value
3. If external_tags = 0 and tag = automation_notify_bounced_{var1value}_{var2value} then update tag2 to automation_notify_bounced and var1 to var1value and var2 to var2value
4. If external_tags = 0 and tag = registered_livestream_co_host_{var1value}*schedule*{var2value} then update tag2 to registered_livestream_co_host and var1 to var1value and var2 to var2value
5. If external_tags = 0 and tag = attended_recurring_live_class_{var1value}*rec_schedule*{var2value} then update tag2 to attended_recurring_live_class and var1 to var1value and var2 to var2value
6. If external_tags = 1 then update tag2 to tag value

How to update above cases using 6 update queries?

Please reply with MYSQL Query.

Comment: What you have tried this far? Don't just ask SO community to write code for you. Your fellow developers are happy to help with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join to the table a query that returns 6 rows, 1 for each of your different cases and use [`MySql's string functions`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html) to extract the pieces of strings in the column `tag` which will update the other columns:

```
UPDATE tablename t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 0 external_tags, 'school_signup' tag UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, 'course_enroll' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, 'automation_notify_bounced' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, 'registered_livestream_co_host' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, 'attended_recurring_live_class' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, NULL 
) e ON t.external_tags = e.external_tags AND (e.tag IS NULL OR INSTR(t.tag, CONCAT(e.tag, '_')) = 1)
SET t.tag2 = COALESCE(e.tag, t.tag),
    t.var1 = CASE 
               WHEN t.external_tags = 1 THEN t.var1
               ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(t.tag, CHAR_LENGTH(e.tag) + 2), '_', 1)
             END,
    t.var2 = CASE 
               WHEN t.external_tags = 1 OR INSTR(SUBSTR(t.tag, CHAR_LENGTH(e.tag) + 2), '_') = 0 THEN t.var2
               ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(t.tag, CHAR_LENGTH(e.tag) + 2), '_', -1)
             END
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d55e512e27b5ea3b273d3f55f0279a39).

Comment: Done. Will the above query work for table having around 6 crore rows?

Comment: @Renji what is crores?

Comment: 6 crore = 60 million

Comment: @Renji the query works for any number of rows. Of course the performance decreases for a large dataset.

Comment: So what do you suggest for updating the above case for 60 million records?

Comment: @Renji there is no difference in the code when the dataset is large. If you try it and see that it's taking too long, then divide the process in 6 different processes, 1 for each case: first update the rows with 'course_enroll', then the row with 'automation_notify_bounced' etc.